# "SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received" when connecting vpn

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn

I followed this tutorial  : https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/OpenVPN

Then  I followed this tutorial : https://gist.github.com/gangsta/679e224900003f51ec184b7b8e56968b

This is the  conf file :

```
#Template client.ovpnclient
dev tun
tls-client
proto tcp-client
port 1194
remote vpn1.domain.fr
remote vpn2.domain.fr
client
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun

remote-cert-tls server
ca cert_export_CA-CDS.crt

cipher AES-128-CBC

auth MD5

auth-user-pass login.conf
auth-nocache


route 10.30.0.0 255.255.255.0

dhcp-option DNS 10.44.3.254

redirect-gateway def1
push "redirect-gateway def1"
```

The systemd service gives this error :

```
● openvpn.service - OpenVPN tunnel for
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/service.d
             └─10-timeout-abort.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-04-29 23:20:44 CEST; 30min ago
       Docs: man:openvpn(8)
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage
             https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/HOWTO
   Main PID: 20040 (openvpn)
     Status: "Pre-connection initialization successful"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9334)
     Memory: 1.9M
        CPU: 301ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/openvpn.service
             └─20040 /usr/sbin/openvpn --suppress-timestamps --nobind --config vpn-intranet.ovpn

avril 29 23:43:05 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]81.255.194.33:1194
avril 29 23:43:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: Connection reset, restarting [0]
avril 29 23:43:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
avril 29 23:48:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]84.239.73.91:1194
avril 29 23:48:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]84.239.73.91:1194
avril 29 23:48:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: TCP connection established with [AF_INET]84.239.73.91:1194
avril 29 23:48:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
avril 29 23:48:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]84.239.73.91:1194
avril 29 23:48:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: Connection reset, restarting [0]
avril 29 23:48:06 cyprien-lenovo-yoga openvpn[20040]: SIGUSR1[soft,connection-reset] received, process restarting
```

I tried with NetworkManager-openvpn, it keeps asking for a password without an error message